# Flutter TimeoutException brings Page back

Tags: flutter, multithreading, websocket, async-await, future

I am coding an application that communicates with a WebSocket for all authentication, commands, etc. I added a Timeout to the WebSocket commands, and I handle it in my commands page.

I coded these two methods for handling commands, *WebSocket.dart*:

```
void sendCommand(Command command) {
    logger.log("WebSocket - sending command: ${command.commandType}");

    if (_channel != null) {
        _channel!.sink.add(jsonEncode(command.toJson()));
    } else {
        log('not connected!');
    }
}

Future<dynamic> sendCommandAndWaitForResponse(Command command, {Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30)}) async {
    final completer = Completer<dynamic>();
    StreamSubscription<dynamic>? subscription;

    subscription = _messageController.stream.listen((message) {
        if (message == 'disconnected') {
            subscription?.cancel();
            completer.completeError('WebSocket disconnected');
        } else {
            final decodedMessage = jsonDecode(message);
            if (decodedMessage['Number'] == command.number) {
                subscription?.cancel();
                completer.complete(decodedMessage);
            }
        }
    });

    sendCommand(command);

    return completer.future.timeout(timeout, onTimeout: () {
        subscription?.cancel();
        return Future.error('WebSocket response timeout ${command.commandType}');
    });
}
```

If the WebSocket disconnects, it brings the user back to the authentication page, *Commands.dart*:

```
void onWebSocketDisconnected() {
    logger.log("WebSocket disconnected");

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => AuthenticationPage(
                websocket: widget.websocket,
                logger: logger,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Here is the problem: if the WebSocket disconnects while a user is waiting for a command response, it brings the user back to the authentication page, but then once the TimeoutException is thrown it brings the commands page back. My guess is that I need to abort the threads waiting for the response.

I send commands this way, *Commands.dart*:

```
Future<void> _showUtility() async {
    logger.log("Sending 'Show Utility' command...");

    loadingOverlay.show();

    var command = ShowUtilityCommand(
        number: widget.websocket.messageCounter,
    );

    try {
        Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = await widget.websocket.sendCommandAndWaitForResponse(command);
        Response response = Response.fromJson(responseJson);
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
        logger.log('Error: Timeout - ${e.message}');
    } on String catch (e) {
        if (e == 'WebSocket disconnected') {
            logger.log('Error: WebSocket disconnected');
        } else {
            logger.log('Error: $e');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        logger.log('Error: $e');
    }

    loadingOverlay.hide();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried implementing a CancellationToken class, that would set isCanceled attribute and based on that it would try to not return the error, but it still continued a part of the code in the Commands page and brought it back to screen. I was expecting to remain on the Authentication page.